# R: Barplot - How to remove a bar

Tags: r, excel

Hi there I am new to R and I have produced a barplot, with the code below, however for the data set "Control" I do not have data for the ungrazed rate, therefore there is a line where the bar should be on the graph (see image below) but no data! Is there a way for me to get rid of that? Do I need to edit the original table of data on my txt file?

```
    barplot(xtabs(ana$Infiltration ~ ana$Grazing + ana$Burn ),beside = TRUE, col = c( "tan4", "darkgreen"), xlab = "Burn Treatment", names = c( "Control", "Long Rotation", "Burned 1954", "Short Rotation" ) , ylab = "Mean Infiltration Rate (mm/h) " , legend = c( "Grazed", "Ungrazed"), args.legend = list(title = "Graze Treatment", x = "topright", cex = .7), ylim = c(0, 40000)  )
```

[image: barplot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option would be to replace the 0 values from the `xtabs` to missing values i.e. `NA`

```
tbl <- xtabs(Infiltration ~ Grazing + Burn, data = ana )
is.na(tbl) <- tbl == 0

barplot(tbl,beside = TRUE, 
  col = c( "tan4", "darkgreen"), xlab = "Burn Treatment",
   names = c( "Control", "Long Rotation", "Burned 1954", "Short Rotation" ) , 
   ylab = "Mean Infiltration Rate (mm/h) " , 
   legend = c( "Grazed", "Ungrazed"),
   args.legend = list(title = "Graze Treatment", x = "topright",
             cex = .7), ylim = c(0, 20)  )
```

-output

Below, we have the one without the NA replacement on the left and the right with NA replacement

[image]

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
ana <- data.frame(Infiltration = sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE),
               Grazing = sample(c("Grazed", "Ungrazed"), 20, replace = TRUE),
               Burn = sample(c("Control", "Long Rotation", "Burned 1954", "Short Rotation"),
                   20, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Comment: So do I need to change the data in the table saved as txt to write N/A?

Comment: It is the control that I want to change not the short rotation -  I know you just used that as an example, however I am just wondering if your code would still be applicable @akrun

Comment: @BelleT  I was just creating a reproducible example.  In your case, the control is having 0 values.  So, it should work